# Как реализовать логику для удаления продуктов из корзины с помощью метода sub из 2 словарей

Tags: python

Подскажите, как лучше написать код. Необходимо реализовать логику для удаления продуктов из корзины с помощью магического метода **sub** из 2 словарей.

```
class Products:
    def __init__(self, products, bonuses=0):
        self.bonuses = bonuses
        self.products = products

    def get_products_price(self):
        return sum(self.products.values()) - self.bonuses

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            return Products(self.products, self.bonuses + other)
        elif isinstance(other, Products):
            new_products = {}
            for product, price in self.products.items():
                if product not in new_products:
                    new_products[product] = price
            for product, price in other.products.items():
                if product not in new_products:
                    new_products[product] = price
            return Products(new_products)
```

Comment: ну вы бы свой код привели. то за классы у вас, что именно не получается? написать дандер-метод или написать функцию по вычитания одного словаря из другого?

Comment: Вот этот код) нужно вставить еще sub

Comment: для начала - почему вы пишете логику добавления продуктов в классе Products? я бы сделал класс Product чисто для продуктов, и класс Basket. а уже в классе Basket писал бы дандеры для добавления/удаления товаров.

Answer (score 0):

```
 def __sub__(self, other):
    new_products = {}
    for product, price in self.products.items():
        if product not in other.products:
            new_products[product] = price
    return Products(new_products)

def __rsub__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, int):
        return Products(self.products, self.bonuses - other)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]